# Local variable not initialized catch-22

Tags: java

Java newbie here!  I need to create a Java method that keeps a running total of the values passed to it.  However, if I use a local variable and keep initializing it, I will lose my running balance.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a member variable of the class. If you want to count values passed to all objects of the class use a static variable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.. declare a field.

```
public class Summation{

    private int total;

    public void sumUp(int n){
        total += n;
   }
}
```

In case you are interested, in other languages like C/C++ you *can* do it by:

```
 void sumUp(int n){
    static int total = 0; 
    total+=n;

 }
```

This ensures that `total` is declared once, and adds it up on subsequent calls to `sumUp`. As Java is object oriented it isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Well Lews already answered it. But as you are newbie please also understand the logic behind it.All local variable are stored in stack which gets destroyed as thread comes out of method and instance variable are stored in heap which will stay for the lifetime of object life. It should help you to understand other basics of java